# Why can't initialize my class from an initializer list even if it derives from std::list?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, list-initialization

I have the following code.

```
#include <utility>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class Pair: public std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>{
    Pair (unsigned int h, unsigned int l) : pair(h,l){};
};
class PairList: public std::list<Pair>{};


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    PairList pl = {{800,400},{800,400}};
}
```

I compile it using MinGW g++ of v4.6 with the command line
`g++ -std=c++0x Test.cpp -o test.exe`
and got the error:
`error: could not convert '{{800, 400}, {800, 400}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'PairList'`
But if in main() I write
`list<pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>> pl =  {{800,400},{800,400}};`
all works fine.
WTF?

Comment: @ExplodingRat when editing a poor title, it doesn't help much to simply fix minor typos. It is recommended to write a meaningful title and not bother getting worthless titles with perfect spelling.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways:

1. Don't inherit the from the standard classes, use `typedef` instead:

   ```
   typedef std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> Pair;
   typedef std::list<Pair> PairList;
   ```
2. Implement the correct constructors in your inherited classes (taking [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as argument), the base class constructors can't be used automatically.

I recommend the first alternative, as the standard classes (with few exceptions) are *not* designed to be inherited.

Comment: 1. What if I need extend base class (especially pair<>) by my own methods?
2. Sorry, I implemented constructor for PairList. See my correction to the question

Comment: @OlegG And I just updated my answer with the argument the constructors need to be able to use initializer lists.

Comment: @JoachimPielborg The solution with `std::initializer_list` looks ugly for me. For now at least.

Comment: @Joachim the base class constructors can be used automatically if you use inherited constructors (`using std::list<Pair>::list;`). However, I don't think any compiler currently implements those.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes GCC 4.6 definetly does not support it. It is checked.

Comment: @oleg you would need gcc 4.8, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). As to the inheritance issue, you *could* inherit privately. It is less frowned upon than public inheritance, and almost completely safe (i.e. you need to try hard to mess it up).